# How to find sprite's transparent pixel in cocos2d for android?

Tags: android, cocos2d-x

I have added sprite on scene like this:-

```
CCSprite *s = CCSprite::create("three.png");
s->setPosition( ccp(size.width/2, size.height/2) );
this->addChild(s, -1);
```

Now i want's to get transparent pixel of the sprite on touch move.

Please help me someone.
Thanks in advance

Comment: what do you mean by `get transparent pixel of the sprite on touch move` , can you elaborate ???

Comment: I presume this is cocos2d-x, not cocos2d-iphone, right? I think the user wants to know which parts of the sprite are transparent, unfortunately there's no simple (built-in) way to do that. Usually solutions involve glReadPixel.

Comment: @LearnCocos2D yeah that right.